# Backbone search collection for model that has attribute that matches string

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

I am writing a search function at the moment for my Backbone application, the idea is that a user can enter a string and the app will search for and return any matching models where the string appears in any of its attributes. So far I have the following,

view function run on keyup,

```
this.results = this.collection.search(letters);
```

This runs the following code located in the collection,

```
search: function( filterValue ) {

    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase();

    var filterThroughValue = function(data) {

        return _.some(_.values(data.toJSON()), function(value) {
            console.log(value);
            if(value != undefined) {
                value = (!isNaN(value) ? value.toString() : value);
                return value.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) >= 0;
            }
        });
    };

    return App.Collections.filterCollection = this.filter(filterThroughValue);
}
```

However running this I get the following error,

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

this error is shown as being the line `return value.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) >= 0;` and this error gets returned whether or not I use a string I know exists in a model of the collection.

Is there a fix for this, or a better way of searching and returning only models that have models that contain the search string?

Answer (score 1):

Since you just want a string representation of value, you can probably just check if value has a toString method. Note that String also has a toString method, so this will work if value is a String.

```
return _.some(_.values(data.toJSON()), function(value) {
  if(value && value.toString) {
    return value.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) >= 0;
  }
  return false;
}
```